# How to do extra validation on sign in (using Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I'm using Devise -- how can I do an extra validation on sign in?

I want to verify the the account logging in is associated with the current subdomain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page from the Devise Wiki on GitHub: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in)

I think that will work for what you are talking about.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it was causing something nasty and making the server quit. I'll try again

Comment: If you still get the error go ahead and post the error message up here.

Comment: Umm... the provided link is empty :(